# After changing developing OS, it shows "Unresolved reference: synthetic"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

## Abstract

I am developing an Android app and I am new to it. I used to develope this app on **Windows 10 Pro** and everything works fine, no error. Recently, I have erased my Windows 10 and use Manjaro Linux (KDE version). When I pull my code from GitHub and open in Android Studio, the line: `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*` shows have the error: `Unresolved reference: synthetic`

## my imports

```
package com.marco.booking_app.auth

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.marco.booking_app.MainActivity
import com.marco.booking_app.R
import com.marco.booking_app.extensions.Extensions.toastError
import com.marco.booking_app.utils.FirebaseUtils.firebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.* // It shows "Unresolved reference: synthetic"
```

## build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## build.gradle (App)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marco.booking_app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
}
```

## Questions

1. What makes this error occur?
2. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your code at least once for the build-time generated synthetic code to be available. Just importing the project does not build it.

Note that synthetic view binding with kotlin-android-extensions is deprecated. You can use e.g. [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) instead.